# Registering WCF Web Service breaks my ASP.Net HTML Web Form Routing

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, model-view-controller, routes

**(SOLUTION BELOW)**
 

<strike>When adding a WCF Web Service to an existing ASP .Net MVC application, my Login form tries routing the login token through the web service when I register the web service route in the app start.</strike>

What I mean is this, ***if I do not register*** the route to my web service *(like below)*

```
Protected Sub Application_Start()
       ...
       RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("MyWebServiceName", New WebServiceHostFactory(), GetType(MyWebServiceName)))
       RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
       ...
End Sub
```

It reroutes my Login properly like this...

`http://localhost:49322/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F`

However, ***if I do register*** the web service route, it attempts to reroute my Login like this...
`http://localhost:49322/EISFacialWebService?action=Login&controller=Account&ReturnUrl=%2F`

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I solved this by refactoring

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyService.svc", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)))
```

from the `Globals.asax` file

into the `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.vb` file...

1. Added .svc extension to route ignores  ( `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}")` )
2. Add the WCF Service route ***AFTER*** the default routes are mapped.

```
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

/* [ PART 1 ] */
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}")

    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Inbox", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )

/* [ PART 2 ] */
    routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("MyService.svc", New WebServiceHostFactory(), GetType(MyService)))

End Sub
```